# My way to handle purchases made at the same time in Mysql is correct?

Tags: mysql, transactions

I know that single queries in Mysql are executed in an atomic way (there is the autocommit mode enabled by default)
But look at this query:

```
Update products set Amount = Amount-1 Where Amount>0 AND ID_PRODUCT = 5;
```

But what about concurrency? Namely more than one user can exec about in the same time the same query. For instance 2 users buy the same product when the availability is 1. When they purchase the product there is one, but when in the backend the query is executed the other user has already purchased the product thus the condition `Amount>0` is not satisfied and the update is not applied.  I would kindly know if this model is robust and safe for my application?
Or I have to use a lock or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is atomic. It can be run more than once, even concurrently, but you will need to pay close attention to the result to see if any rows were modified.

In the case of running out of stock you'll get a result indicating no rows were modified, or in other words, it failed to subtract stock due to the condition.

Some systems prefer to move the stock around from a stock table like this to another "order" table, much like a ledger, so you can be sure you're not subtracting inventory that then goes missing if not properly purchased. A ledger makes it easy to unwind and return stock if someone abandons an order, makes a return, etc.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I understand, for instance I'm using PDO in Php and I have to check if `rowCount()==0` and if it is the case the purchase was not successful.  Rather If I remove `Amount>0` i will have trouble, is it right?        I have not fully understood the second part, you mean to have a table orders and another table orders_details and store here the amount (and link table products with order_details)?

Comment: Yes, if you remove the stock condition it will keep subtracting into the negative without limit, defeating the point.

Comment: The second part is to help with understanding why the stock decremented. Counters like this with no backing data can often get out of sync with reality, and it's good to know why. A ledger gives you a transactional breakdown of everything added to and removed from the stock.

Comment: Ah yes, now I understood. You mean that this value is dependant from the state of the order(I'm not native english speacker and the term ledger was not familiar to me) and the system you suggest is the best practice to handle a return, abandoned order and so on (in this cases it will simpler restore).